# Browsers are not working in Windows11

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet, windows-11

I cannot access the websites through browsers. Here are some screenshots:

Chrome:[image]

[image]

firefox: [image]

Edge:[image]
[image]

I have tried safe mode.
[image]

I have reinstalled Windows 11 and have done all the updates.

I have tried different WIFI's.

I have run tron script for any malware/virus but the results were clean.

Settings page downloads and favourites pages wont work either.
Any recommendation about what causing this would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does it happen with Chrome in Incognito mode? And when booting in Safe Mode with Network?

Comment: yes mate it does

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the browsers?

Comment: will try and will let you know.

Comment: I did reset the pc and choose to keep the files. After windows booted installed browsers same thing. Safe mode, private browsing nothing would work. Now I get the following error  from Firefox: SEC_ERROR_KEYGEN_FAIL. When I click favorites in Edge all I see is css codes.

Comment: Are you sure you tested when booting in Safe Mode with Network? Because this looks like some installed software is interfering. Or something else that you did, after doing Reset Windows

Comment: Yes mate. I have updated the topic. Please see the screenshot on safe mode. Also I have tried few more tricks. they are on updated topic. I never came accross to something like this. I am very desperate for help.

Comment: Your last Edge image is displaying the URL `edge://settings/profiles`, which is a CSS file that is used inside the `edge://settings` page. In fact. all the images are of included CSS files, rather than of the including pages. You must have changed some settings on all your browsers to cause this.

Comment: I formated the drive and installed windows 11 from scratch and have not changed any setting. I was surprised to see fresh windows 11 giving me same trouble. it should load setting but instead loads only raw css and javascript combinations.

Comment: If not the PC, it might be the router - try to factory reset it (beware of settings that may need to be re-applied). Although this problem seems too strange to be the router.

Comment: If it was the router settings and favourites would load, those do not need router to be displayed.

Comment: [Here is a solution for chromium based browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398022/disable-gzip-compression-in-chrome)

Comment: I installed the extension and left empty value instead of "gzip;q=0,deflate;q=0" the websites start loading then chrome closes it self. I cannot view the version of Chrome due to problem above but I have installed it few hours ago so imagine its the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

After 6 days I was able to make Firefox work.

I typed

```
about:config
```

in address bar and then searched for the following

```
network.http.accept-encoding.secure
```

then changed the value from

```
gzip, deflate, br
```

to

```
gzip, deflate
```

Now Firefox loading all the websites correctly. I need to do this for Chrome and Edge. I tried but I could not find where I can change the encoding settings for other browsers. Any recommendation is highly appreciated.